# Two columns bullet list when using *ngFor

Tags: angular, html-lists, ngfor

Here is what I got. The program print out a one column bullet list of heroes. I want this list to be presented in i two columns list when the program loop over the array.

Something like this:

```
         Windstorm        Bombasto
         Magneta          Tornado
         Storm            Basto
         Magnet           Thorn
         Batman
```

*src/app/app.component.html*

```
        <p>Heroes:</p>
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
              {{ hero }}
            </li>
          </ul>
```

*src/app/app.component.ts*

```
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'Tour of Heroes';
      heroes = [
        new Hero(1, 'Windstorm'),
        new Hero(8, 'Bombasto'),
        new Hero(9, 'Magneta'),
        new Hero(12, 'Tornado'),
        new Hero(18, 'Batman'),
        new Hero(28, 'Robin'),
        new Hero(35, 'Star')
      ];
      myHero = this.heroes[0];
    }
```

Here is what the program print now

```
    Heroes:
     List item

        Windstorm
        Bombasto
        Magneta
        Tornado
        Storm
        Basto
        Magnet
        Thorn
        Batman
```

I want this list to be presented in two bullet columns, I just cannot figur out how to do it

Answer (score 3):

you can use `column-count` to achieved that, just give your `ul` class as shown below:

**src/app/app.component.html**

```
<p>Heroes:</p>
  <ul class="hero-column">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
      {{ hero }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**src/app/app.component.scss**

```
.hero-column {
 column-count:2 
}
```